# Edit a user profile field on front end

Tags: user-meta

I have a user profile field that I would like to allow users to edit, but I have the backend dashboard/profile disabled. If I only know the meta (dbem_paypal_account), how can I make this work? I've tried a few plugins, but have had no luck so far.

Basically, I would like to add a text field onto a page allowing the user to change this particular field. I hope that's clear. Thanks yall!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ACF is great for managing user custom fields, but it's also fairly simple to do what you're asking using just `update_user_meta()` to save custom data and then retrieve it with `$user->get( 'whatever' );`

Here's an example of a form that let's users set and update their twitter handle:

```php
<?php 

// Grab the current user (Or redirect to login page)
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( !$user->exists() ) {
  wp_safe_redirect(wp_login_url(home_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])));
  exit;
}


// Check if form was submitted
if ( isset($_POST['submitted']) ) {

  // Verify nonce
  if ( !isset($_POST['_wpnonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['_wpnonce'], 'user_form' ) ) {
    wp_die("Invalid nonce.");
  }

  update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'twitter_handle', $_POST['twitter_handle'] );

  // Do a PGP redirect to prevent submitting the same for data multiple times.
  // Read more about PGP here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get
  wp_safe_redirect( add_query_arg( 'updated', '', home_url($_POST['_wp_http_referer']) ) );
  exit;
}

get_header();

?>

<?php if ( isset($_GET['updated']) ) : ?>
<p>Your twitter handle has been updated!</p>
<?php endif; ?>

<form method="POST">
  <label for="twitter_handle">Twitter Handle</label>
  <input type="text" id="twitter_handle" name="twitter_handle" value="<?php echo esc_attr($user->get("twitter_handle")); ?>">
  <?php wp_nonce_field("user_form"); ?>
  <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1">
  <button type="submit">Save changes</button>
</form>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Get the user ID.

Assuming the user is logged in, which they would have to be to save data associated with their profile, [you can grab their user id](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_user_id/) with the get_current_user_id function. That will be necessary, otherwise you're not going to be able to attach something to their profile.

Step 2: Create a front end page with a form.

I've done this before, using ACF, so I'm not 100% sure how your set up will function for this, but conceptually I had added custom fields to a profile with ACF. Then I made a front end form submission with ACF, and used its [save post](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-save_post/) functions to push form field inputs to the posts, or profiles, as it were. This wasn't easy - I spent a lot of time doing it and I had to get really familiar with how WordPress user profiles worked.

Regardless, I don't think you're going to find an out of the box solution, I think you're looking at custom development. If that's not your wheelhouse, you'll want to hire a WordPress dev.